# TortoiseSVN - Missing "Advanced" panel

Tags: tortoisesvn

I'm here because I have an issue related to my settings in TortoiseSVN.

Indeed, I have 2 computers on Windows 7 with TortoiseSVN but on one of them i don't have the "Advanced" panel.

[image: TortoiseSVN - With "Advanced" panel]

[image: TortoiseSVN - Without "Advanced" panel]

Someone could be able to explain me why?

Comment: which TSVN version do you use?

Comment: I use 1.6.15 verison

Comment: why do you still use such and old version? Is updating to 1.9.2 an option?